# What is the time out of a memcached counter created using the increment call in memcached service?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

When will the value created using the following call time out?

Is the expiry renewed by subsequent calls to increment?

```
MemcacheService cacheService;
cacheService.increment(key, delta, initialValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Memcache is a [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) cache as pointed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview#How_Cached_Data_Expires).

If you don't set an experiration the behavior is the following:

> By default, values stored in memcache are retained as long as
>   possible. Values may be evicted from the cache when a new value is
>   added to the cache if the cache is low on memory. When values are
>   evicted due to memory pressure, the least recently used values are
>   evicted first.

If you do set an expiration:

> The value will be evicted no later than this time, though it may be
>   evicted for other reasons.